# Node Error on installing custom script

Tags: node.js

I have some code that a programmer made for our company using Node 0.10 that I am trying to update to node 6.9 in a dev environment. I am not a Node guru, this is a project helping me to learn Node and the code left for us.

When I run the reccomended install script, I get this error:

```
# node install.js --production
path.js:7
    throw new TypeError('Path must be a string. Received ' + inspect(path));
    ^

TypeError: Path must be a string. Received undefined
    at assertPath (path.js:7:11)
    at Object.dirname (path.js:1324:5)
    at new daemon (/var/www/ClientResponder/node_modules/node-linux/lib/daemon.js:208:30)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/www/ClientResponder/install/install.js:13:11)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:604:10)
```

I look at the file install.js, line 11 starts off like this:

```
/**
 * Created by Tim.
 */

var Service = require('node-linux').Service;

var env = null;
if(process.argv.length === 3){
    env = process.argv[2] === "--production" ? "production" : "staging";
}

// Create a new service object
var svc = new Service({
    name:'Client Responder',
    description: "Optional web server which can be deployed to a Media Server providing user clients the ability to ping the server for speed tests.",
    script: '/var/www/ClientResponder/server.js',
    env: [{
        name: "NODE_ENV",
        value: env ? env : "staging"
    },{
        name: "PORT",
        value: 8888
    }]
});

// Listen for the "install" event, which indicates the
// process is available as a service.
svc.on('install',function(){
    svc.start();
});

svc.install();
```

I didn't see anything there about the path, so I look at the daemon.js file at line 208 and get this:

```
cwd: {      
  enumerable: false,          
  writable: true,          
  configurable: false,          
  value: config.cwd || p.dirname(this.script)
},
```

What am I missing here? I realize it is hard to know when you don't have full access to all source code, what more can I provide that would help short of full access?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `util.inspect` [docs](https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_util_inspect_object_options) instead of `inspect` ?

Comment: I don't know, it is just part of the error msg.

Comment: Change `inspect` for `util.inspect`, also add an require on top of the file, and please provide the `if` (if any) where this error is thrown (maybe line 6 of `path.js`)

Comment: I included the full source for that file, the rest seems to be coming from an external node library. I am not sure where the inspect originates since path.js seems to be part of node itself. There is no path.js file that is part of my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The suggested workaround here is to follow [this issue](https://github.com/coreybutler/node-linux/issues/32).

And change:

```
var svc = new Service({
    name:'Client Responder',
    description: "Optional web server which can be deployed to a Media Server providing user clients the ability to ping the server for speed tests.",
    script: '/var/www/ClientResponder/server.js',
    env: [{
        name: "NODE_ENV",
        value: env ? env : "staging"
    },{
        name: "PORT",
        value: 8888
    }]
});
```

To:

```
var svc = new Service({
    name:'Client Responder',
    description: "Optional web server which can be deployed to a Media Server providing user clients the ability to ping the server for speed tests.",
    script: 'server.js', // here
    cwd: '/var/www/ClientResponder/', // and here
    env: [{
        name: "NODE_ENV",
        value: env ? env : "staging"
    },{
        name: "PORT",
        value: 8888
    }]
});
```